error in vue.js application : ./node_modules/@formkit/themes/dist/index.mjs Module parse failed: Unexpected token (63:55)
i am facing bellow erro on compiling vue.js application and ia am using node version 20. and when i try with some old version they give another error. please check and let me know. where i am doing any mistake. and why i am not able compiling my application
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                    3:36:20 AM

 error  in ./node_modules/@formkit/themes/dist/index.mjs

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (63:55)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     Object.assign(iconRegistry, icons);
|   }
>   if (isClient && !themeWasRequested && documentStyles?.getPropertyValue("--formkit-theme")) {
|     themeDidLoad();
|     themeWasRequested = true;

 @ ./src/main.js 8:0-25
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8085&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./node_modules/@formkit/vue/dist/index.cjs

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (72:41)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|       const isRequired = vue.ref(false);
|       const checkForRequired = (parsedRules) => {
>         isRequired.value = (parsedRules ?? []).some(
|           (rule) => rule.name === "required"
|         );

 @ ./src/main.js 7:0-53 24:8-14 24:16-29
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8085&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

here is pakage.json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ethereumjs/common": "^2.6.2",
    "@ethereumjs/tx": "^3.5.0",
    "@formkit/themes": "^1.6.2",
    "@formkit/vue": "^1.6.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "bip39": "^3.0.4",
    "bs-custom-file-input": "^1.3.4",
    "core-js": "^3.21.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "ethers": "^5.5.4",
    "idb": "^7.0.0",
    "idb-keyval": "^6.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "localforage": "^1.10.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-forge": "^1.3.1",
    "qrcode": "^1.5.0",
    "url-exist": "^3.0.1",
    "vlf": "^1.1.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
    "vue-input-autowidth": "^1.0.11",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12",
    "vue-stripe-js": "^1.0.1",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2",
    "web3": "^1.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.31"
  }
}


i have tryied many time to add loders or other staff. but not works
babel-loader and @babel/preset-env  to config file
bable.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}

vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/app',
  lintOnSave: false,
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8085,
},
}


